# How convert docx or html to pdf use gdrive api?

Tags: php, api, pdf, docx

I need convert html or docx use grive api.

My code

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);


    $content = file_get_contents('template.html');//template.docx 
    $fileMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => 'test', // name file
        'mimeType' => 'application/pdf', // mime type for save in gdrive
        //'parents' => array($id_folder) 
            ));
    $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
        'data' => $content, // file
        'mimeType' => 'text/html', // application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        //'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'fields' => 'id')); //
```

File upload to dgrive normal but when I open it test.pdf i see this error

> Failed to load other pages

But my file have only one page.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the examples [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php#L91-L99). In Particular I dont think you need to have fields element in there which i cant find in documentation. When you upload file as text/html make sure you have correct meta data and enable multi-part as you are doing both content and meta data in one go.

I would also suggest doing it in small steps and first let it be very simple html content and try that if that works it might be the case with your content that is not letting pdf come out as normal.

If you work through some of these examples then it would be easy to debug if the problem is in meta data, content or anything else.

Comment: Do a basic test of uploading a small text file. Use the example code and if that works than modify it step by step.

Comment: I upload small txt file and get same error https://drive.google.com/open?id=19TB7mnYf-imm42QykT0cj9RVir5TZW8F

Comment: You have uplaoded a pdf file. Try uploading txt/html and then once that is done then try downloading same file in pdf format. I think you are trying to upload html/txt as pdf which wont work.